# What is the other endpoint when the midpoint is $(20, 20)$ and the endpoint is $(10, 10)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need to know the answer but I don't remember the formula. I need to know it for a desktop application I am working on.

Comment: You might not need a formula if you draw a picture and think about it.

Comment: If you can't remember a formula then derive the formula on your own.  If you have two points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$ what point is exactly half way between them?  The $x_m$ value must be exactly half way between $x_0$ and $x_1$ and the $y_m$ value must be exactly half way between $y_0$ and $y_1$.  .... To be honest I don't expect anyone to have a formula memorized but I expect everyone to be able to derive this on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the starting point and endpoint are $(x_{0},y_{0})$ and $(x_{1},y_{1})$.

Then the midpoint is given by $$(x_{m},y_{m})=(\frac{x_{0}+x_{1}}{2},\frac{y_{0}+y_{1}}{2}).$$

Answer (score 2):

Try to derive the formula if you can't remember.

Commons sense says that horizontally the the $x$ value has gone from $x =10$ to $x=20$.  That's a total change of $\Delta x = (20 - 10)=10$. That's half the distance it has to go so we if it goes another $10$ (or a total horizontal distance of $20$) so final horizontal positions is $x=30$.

The same reasoning for vertical distance yields the final vertical position is $y=30$ and the other endpoint is $(30,30)$.

And we can derive to formula that if the two endpoints are $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ then the horizontal change is $\Delta =x_1 - x_0$ and the vertical change is $\Delta y = y_1-y_0$.  The midpoint must do half those distances so midpoint $(x_m,y_m)=(x_0 + \frac 12\Delta x, y_0+\frac 12 \Delta y) = (x_1 - \frac 12\Delta x, y_1 -\frac 12\Delta y)=$

$(x_0 + \frac 12(x_1 - x_0), y_0 +\frac 12(y_1-y_0))= (x_1- \frac 12(x_1 - x_0), y_1-\frac 12(y_1-y_0))$

$(\frac 12 x_0 + \frac 12 x_1,\frac 12 y_0 + \frac 12 y_1) = (\frac {x_0+x_1}2, \frac {y_0+y_1}2)$.

You should note the similarity to the formula for averages.  The midpoint is  the "average" of two points.

...

so using formula.  $(x_0, y_0) = (10,10)$ and $(x_m, y_m) = (20,20)$ what is $(x_1,y_1)$?

Well.  $(20,20) = (x-m,y_m)=(\frac {x_0+x_1}2, \frac {y_0+y_1}2) = (\frac {10+x_1}2, \frac {10+y_1}2)$.

So $\frac {10+x_1}2 = 20$ and $\frac {10+y_1}2 = 20$ and solve.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{y_2-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x_2-x_0}{x_1-x_0}=2$$

Comment: And what if the line is horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @Integrand It is just a hint that includes the general idea. If the line becomes vertical or horizontal, then one term must be used without the other, which is not defined.

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate as a comment